# Past reward history in polkadot.js

Tags: polkadot-js, kusama, era, rewards

`api.query.staking.erasRewardPoints(era)` query returns reward history for selected era.

And only last 84 eras reward history is available.

I want to get reward history from first era.

How can I get reward history for all eras?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed you'll need to use api.at with a block hash of an earlier block to continue searching beyond the history depth.